# How to resize a subview when another subview changes its position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am implementing `iAds` in my project that to share single instance of `iAds` in all `VC's` by declaring it in subclass of a `ViewController` as `adBannerVC` and all other view controllers are subclassed using the `adBannerVC` and `iAds` are shown in bottom of `VC's` by sending it a subView of VC's like this..

[image: before iAds is shown]   [image: after iAds is shown]

Now, when `iAds` appear in bottom, the view at bottom changes its position and the other subView (scrollView) in the VC must also resize without using `AutoLayout`. Help me to overcome this. Thanks..

Comment: have you tried resetting the new frame size to scrollview in iAd delegate method by reducing the iAd View height?

Comment: @DineshRaja i tried delegate method and works great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue using `Delegate Method` in `adBannerVC` as below

```
@interface AdBannerController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
@private
    ADBannerView *ad;
    BOOL adIsVisible;
    BOOL displayed;

}
```

and implemented this `delegate` method to resizes `views` in each `VC's`